# Splitting windows on startup

Tags: window, init-file

**How do I split my windows on startup like so:**

```
_____________
|  A  |  B  |
|_____|_____|
|     C     |
|___________|
```

Comment: Have a look to the "Grid Layout" wiki [article](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GridLayout), split the window 2x2 and close the lower right one

Comment: As you become more acquainted with Emacs, you may wish to consider displaying certain buffers and creating the window layout simultaneously -- e.g., one could be shell, one could be your todo list, and one could be a calendar.

Comment: Did I answer your question? Because if not, feel free to tell me.

Comment: @KingShimkus Yes you did, I simply forgot to check the checkmark. Thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put the following code in your `.emacs` file:

```
(split-window-below)
(split-window-right)
```

Another option that you can add to your `.emacs` file is:

```
(split-window-vertically)
(split-window-horizontally)
```

Comment: Nope, this does not work. It puts a a large window on the right, and smaller one on the bottom

Comment: Try switching the two commands.

Comment: Why would I switch the commands?

Comment: @KingShimkus because the first split splits the **entire** window, while all subsequent splits split just the **current** buffer. Try it out and you will see the difference

Comment: I originally messed up by switching the two lines of code. Once @Asad-ullahKhan pointed it out, I changed it. I apologize for the misunderstanding.

Comment: When I manually run these functions, I get a different result than when I put them in the init file. Do I need to delay the execution somehow?

Answer (score 6):

An alternative, which offers far more than you require, is to use [workgroups.el](https://github.com/tlh/workgroups.el). It will open Emacs in any of several definable configurations, let you switch among them and load the files you require. When you are doing development which requires several files open at once, it 
enables you to start working much faster. I use it a lot.